# Join strings in list by string in C#

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

In Objective-C there is a method on NSArray which lets us join all elements by a string, so all the strings in the array will be joined by that string.

```
NSArray* arr = @[@"Hello", @"world"];
NSString* mystring = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Any similar thing for something like a List in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var mystring = string.Join(" ", myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but it's on the `String` class in C#:

```
var arr = new[] { "Hello", "world" };
var mystring = String.Join(" ", arr);
```

This works with different object types too (as [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) has a [`Join<T>(string IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) overload):

```
var arr = new[] { 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };
var mystring = String.Join(" ", arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Join

```
var joinedString = string.Join(" ", arr);
```